# JSON object via jQuery post to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, object

I know, there are plenty of questions out there, but none of them worked for me.

I build an array with normal javascript objects in javascript and sent it via `jquery.post` to the server. However on the server, I can't access the data using `php $obj->value` . I tried `json_decode/encode` and so on.

This is what `console.log(data)` gives me, before sending it to the server.

[image]

Than on the php part I only do this:

```
 $data= $_POST['data'];
 print_r($data);
```

The output of print_r is:

[image]

And thats how my Jquery post looks like:

```
    $.post("programm_eintragen.php",{
            data: data,

        }).success(
            function(data){                 
                    //success

        }).error(
            function(){
            console.log("Error post ajax " );
        },'json');
```

Could somebody tell me:

**how I can access my object properties on the php site properly?**

I also get `tried to access non object ....` or  php interprets the json object as a string an `data[0]` returns me  `[`.

I thought, I could do it like this:

```
$data[0]->uebungen[0]
```

**Am I just being silly and missing something?**

**Why is this whole json sending to php thing such a problem?**

Comment: Your JS doesn't POST JSON to your PHP code, it posts an array.  It looks like this is converted to a string literal during POST, which is what `print_r($data)` shows (notice the `"` around the output).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In JavaScript, your're not actually sending a JSON encoded string, your are just sending form data. To actually send a JSON string, you need to convert it (the object) to a string.

```
$.post("programm_eintragen.php",{
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```

On the receiving side (php script) you will have a JSON string. You can decode it.

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

var_dump($data[0]['uebungen'][0]);
```

However, these steps are not necessary. All the json_encoding can be avoided by just accessing the array directly. For this example, ignore the above javascript, and don't change anything in your code.

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
var_dump($data[0]['uebungen'][0]);
```

[example](https://eval.in/172163)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

**JavaScript**

```
var data_obj = {
    "function": "create_customer",
};
$.post({ url: "src/index.php", dataType: "json", data: data_obj }, function (data) {

});
```

**PHP**

```
$json_obj = json_decode(json_encode($_POST));
$function = $json_obj->{"function"};
```

URL is the path relative to `index.html`.