# How to connect frontend (js) and backend (php) in a local application?

Tags: javascript, php, connection, frontend, backend

So confused about how to connect frontend and backend?

Suppose I've got an object `obj` and `var jsonText = JSON.stringify(obj);`

how can I send this `jsonText` to backend (locally, non remote server, no database), using php to get this data and then save the content as a single new JSON file?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Ajax.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Script47 but how to define the post target address?

Comment: Using the `url` parameter which is available.

Comment: Check [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678010/php-server-on-local-machine) to see how to run local php application.

Comment: it would be: `/your-file.php` which is located on `http://localhost/` .. the full path might be something like `http://localhost/your-file.php` and as @Ahamed posted, make sure you have a web server running otherwise what I said is not possible.

Comment: @Script47  thanks :) If the target file is `example.php`, what would be the content of this `example.php`?

Comment: @KAFFEECKO have you looked at the link I provided?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service... please try some things out and come back when you get stuck.  There are many tutorials out there on how to do this basic task.  At the very least, here is one example I found that may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24722126/747678

Comment: @Clayton ya... i've tried using XMLHttpRequest send the data to php earlier, then suddenly my mind's gone blank...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to query your data from a database or from somewhere else in PHP. Then, you can `echo` it with PHP in a JSON format. In a second step, you can use jQuery or plain JavaScript to make an Ajax call to this PHP file and make something with it.

PHP (data.json.php):

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $output = array();
  // query the data from somewhere
  $output['data'] = "1234";
  echo json_encode($output); // json_encode creates the json-specific formatting
?>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
   url: "data.json.php",
   success: function(result){
      console.log(result);
   }
});
```

The code is untested, but I think you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, it's important to break “boundaries”

Comment: might also want to show how to include jQuery into the code since @KAFFEECKO is a beginner.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 absolutely, but have you changed your answer? 'cause i'm interested in the old one :D it would be better to keep it before this new post. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Clayton yes, every time when i met php :P

Comment: He did not edit it because it doesn't say "edited" in the post.  If a post is edited you can view a revision history of the post by clicking 'edited 3 mins ago' link

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 aha... war getrunken